# Docker Alpine Sqlite security vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

Our container with NodeJS App got scanned by twistlock and poped security vulnerability with SQLITE

```
NB: vulnerability is only 3 days old - upgrade will resolve 4 x Critical and 11 x High vulnerabilities
```

I've browsed node_module for sqlite and sqlite-libs and confirmed that node is not using those, so assumption is that Alpine is using it.

How can I update a version of sqlite inside Alpine@latest?

Comment: If you are installing sqlite via apk, then you'll have to wait for the package to be upgraded by the maintainer of the distribution you are using

Comment: The last update was 8 days ago: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=sqlite&branch=edge

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε do you know how can I manually patch it? im using alpine@latest but the issue is still there. So wondering if I can somehow manually override to use latest version sqlite ?

Comment: Well, up until today, there was no newer version in sqlite than this one. https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html the new version have only been released today.

Comment: I just flagged the package as out of date, so I guess the maintainer will react

Comment: There you go, the package is up to date in the repo:  https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=sqlite&branch=edge

Answer (score 1):

You can always help the Alpine community by flagging a package that you find outdated.

In order to do this:

1. Head to the package list: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages
2. Search for the specific package that you think is outdated, using the search box on top. [image: List item]
3. Click on the *Version* of this package to flag this version as out of date
4. Fill and submit the form you are prompted with, in order to warn the maintainer that the package is out of date

Then, just wait for the maintainer to take action.
You can also follow packages flagged out of date via this page: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/flagged.